# Initialize dataframe columns using an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which has column list. Excel file (columnlist.xls) contents are as follows
(This is an example, I have a lot more columns)
Columns  <-- header row
FirstName
LastName
StreetAddress
City
State

I would like to initialize a dataframe with these columns and later start appending the data.

I tried looping through excel file and assign those to a list and then use dataframe fn for assignment, I know I am doing something wrong, please help with below error - TIA.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_cols = list()
    
    # read the saved columns in .csv file
    dfRepeatingColumns    = pd.read_excel('columnlist.xls', sheet_name ='Repeating')

    for index, row in dfNonRepeatingColumns.iterrows():
        df_cols = df_cols.append(row['Columns'])
```

Error:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Expected O/P
Dataframe df will have all the columns.

Comment: Can't um just read the xls using pandas? Sorry if I didn't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `df_cols = list()` try `df_cols = []`. Also, you don't have to set the `df_columns` equal to `df_columns.append()` so just remove
that in your for loop.

Also, you set `df = pd.DataFrame()` but never use the variable `df` anywhere else in your code

```py
import pandas as pd

df_cols = []
 # read the saved columns in .csv file
dfRepeatingColumns    = pd.read_excel('columnlist.xls', sheet_name ='Repeating')

for index, row in dfNonRepeatingColumns.iterrows():
   df_cols.append(row['Columns'])
```

Comment: i tried, it was the same issue.

Comment: @SriGoverdhanSams check my edit about appending also

Comment: Agree on not using in the current code, but i need to use it to start inserting rows with these new columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear, whether you want a new df with the columns or a new list.
I choose the former.

```
for index, row in old_df.iterrows():
   for col in df.columns:
      new_df.loc[index, col] = row[col]
```